# Thread cross class add item listbox

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox

I have a problem with threads in combination with classes.
For my question I have made a simple code to explain my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace RemoteMonitorServer
{
    public partial class RemoteMonitor : Form
    {
        Thread cThread;
        Server cServer;

        public RemoteMonitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteLog("Programm started!");

            cServer = new Server();
            cThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cServer.StartServer));
            cThread.IsBackground = true;
            cThread.Start();
        }

        public void WriteLog(string sText)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sText);
            listBox1.Items.Add(sText);
        }
    }
}
```

The class has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RemoteMonitorServer
{
    class Server
    {
        public void StartServer()
        {
            RemoteMonitor cTest = new RemoteMonitor();

            cTest.WriteLog("Thread started!");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I start this code, the listbox does get "Programm started!" but not "Thread started!".
Although I get two MessageBox messages, so I believe the method is being called.
There is no error in Visual Studio 2010, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It's because you have an invalid cross-thread call to `listBox1.Items.Add` from the thread running `StartServer`. Not sure why it didn't throw an exception - did you disable invalid cross-thread calls checking?

Comment: No, I did not set checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I got it, it has to do with the instance of RemoteMonitor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace RemoteMonitor
{
    public partial class RemoteMonitor : Form
    {
        Thread cThread;
        Server cServer;

        public RemoteMonitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }

        private void RemoteMonitor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WriteLog("Programm started!");

            cServer = new Server();
            cThread = new Thread(() => cServer.StartServer(this));
            cThread.Start();
        }

        public void WriteLog(string sText)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Action action = () => lsbLogger.Items.Add(sText);
                lsbLogger.Invoke(action);
            }
            else
            {
                lsbLogger.Items.Add(sText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace RemoteMonitor
{
    class Server
    {
        public void StartServer(RemoteMonitor cRemoteMonitor)
        {
            cRemoteMonitor.WriteLog("Thread started!");
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm, thanks for your answers and comments!

Answer (score 2):

```
public delegate void RunAtFormThreadCallBack(Control control, RunningAtFormThread method);
private void RunAtFormThread(Control control, RunningAtFormThread method)
{

        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var callback = new RunAtFormThreadCallBack(RunAtFormThread);
            control.Invoke(callback, new object[] { control, method });
        }
        else
            method.Invoke();
}
```

usage:

```
RunAtFormThread(listBox1, delegate
                            {
   // executing at control thread...
   listBox1.Items.Add(sText); 
   MessageBox.Show(sText);
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, still no error.
When i debug it and put an mmbox before the "method.Invoke();", then the mmbox does come up, but nothing in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) to sync your call to the UI.

```
// get a sync context
private readonly SynchronizationContext _sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Then, send the method to the thread pool to queue up the work:

```
    public void WriteLog(string sText)
    {
        _sync.Send((state) => {
           MessageBox.Show(sText);
           listBox1.Items.Add(sText);
        }, null);
    }
```

Read more at the link I supplied to learn about the difference between the `Send` and `Post` methods as well as the uses for the `state` object in the example above.